# Cancel AsyncTask without loop

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I would like to cancel an AsyncTask in my Android application. The kicker is, my AsyncTask does NOT contain a loop, so I can't use break.

Here is my AsyncTask.doInBackground():

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String location = params[1];
            if(!location.matches("-?[0-9.]*,-?[0-9.]*")) {
                try {
                    location = Util.getLatLngFromMapsQuery(location);
                } catch (UnchainedAPIException e) {
                    setErrorCode(ERROR_GEO);
                    this.cancel(true);
                }
            }
            UnchainedAPI unchainedAPI = new UnchainedAPI(YELP_KEY, YELP_SECRET, YELP_TOKEN, YELP_TOKEN_SECRET,
                    FOURSQUARE_ID, FOURSQUARE_SECRET, GOOGLE_PLACES_KEY);
            try {
                nonChains = unchainedAPI.getUnchainedRestaurants(params[0], location);
            } catch (UnchainedAPIException e) {
                setErrorCode(ERROR_API);
                this.cancel(true);
            }

            if(nonChains.size() == 0) {
                setErrorCode(ERROR_API);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

What can I do here?

Comment: Based on what you want to cancel ?? I feel this method will complete and end, I don't see anything which is holding up the thread that you want to kill it or stop the method execution ..

Comment: check this for a good example on correct way to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AsyncTask.cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
```

does the trick.

or from inside the task:

```
cancel(true);
```

Comment: I thought that would work...see my code above, I have this.cancel(true) but no dice...

Comment: theres no need to cancel it there, you could just let the method end as there isn't anything blocking happening after that. Returning the method will just stop whatever it is doing.

Comment: Hmm...I think you're right. Let me try the return thing first...can't believe I didn't think of that first :P

Answer (score 1):

If you need to break the AsyncTask from doInBackground() just use

```
return null;
```

where you need to break. From onPostExecute() you can use

```
this.cancel(true);
```